# Is "generalization" a good tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Recently I've come across the tag "generalization", see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generalization). It's relatively new and there is only one question (Edit: now removed) under it. However, I don't think it's that useful, taking into consideration there isn't any mathematical content associated with it. On the other hand, it's quite vague whether or not a question should be tagged "generalization", maybe when we spot the phrase "in general" or "more generally"? I would like to know the community's opinion on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. It is not a good tag.

Comment: In fact this tag has been created an removed several times in the past as mentioned here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2018/11/16 See also this SEDE query: https://data.stackexchange.com/math/revision/973905/1206822/posts-which-had-given-tag-in-the-past?tagname=generalization (This tag was mentioned a few times in the [Tagging chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=generalization&room=3740).)

Comment: If I may ask, why is this question tagged ([meta-tag:specific-flag])? As far as I can tell, it is unrelated to flagging.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Sorry, I think it's (specific-tag) instead of (specific-flag)...

Comment: @MartinSleziak Btw, why isn't (specific-tag) a tag in meta?

Comment: Why would [specific-tag] be a tag on meta?

Comment: @AsafKaragila But there are (specific-questions), (specific-users), (specific-answers)...

Comment: And...? Those all serve a purpose. What would  be the purpose of [specific-tag] which is not covered by the existing tagging-related tags on meta?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh, I see your point.

Comment: Link to [this tag's entry](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29718/tag-management-2019/29719#29719) in the tag management thread.