# Tag management 2019

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

New year, new tag management thread.

Rules of the game are basically [the same](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27653/43351):

- Post your suggestion as an answer here if you see

  - A particularly bad tag (a rule of thumb: «if I can't imagine a person classifying a tag as either interesting or ignored, I'm getting rid of it»),
  - A tag that should be a synonym of an existing one,
  - A tag that used for two or more completely unrelated things,
  - A need to create a new tag;
- Upvote/downvote/comment as your agree/disagree with suggestions, so please post different suggestions in separate answers;
- Wait a couple of days before implementing a suggestion.
- After the problem described in an answer is resolved, please edit it to say so.
- If your tag suggestion exists in a separate question, please provide a link to the question in your suggestion.

See also:

- The [list with pending and approved synonyms](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms).
- The [tagging chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/tagging) for extended discussion on tagging.
- [Last year's thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27653/43351) to look for suggestions that need to be implemented.

Also, note that one may use `[tag:calculus]` for [calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus), i.e. tags on the main site, and `[meta-tag:discussion]` for [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), i.e. for tags on the meta site.

Answer (score 21):

Proposal to **blacklist** [generalization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generalization)

Reason: It's overly broad and there is no real mathematical content in it. Also, the tag has been created and removed several times.

Comment: As currently defined, it doesn't seem likely to be useful or consistently applied. It doesn't mean what I'd expect it to either, which would be something about dentifying different classes of theorem or proof and generic approaches to generalising ttem. So it's possibly a misleading tag too.

Comment: I will add a link to the previous post about this tag: [Is “generalization” a good tag?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29715)

Answer (score 17):

> **Resolved.**  All questions with [cohomological-operations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cohomological-operations) have been retagged to [cohomology-operations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cohomology-operations) (or neither tag, in a few cases where the tag was inappropriate) and [cohomological-operations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cohomological-operations) will be automatically deleted soon

Apparently we have tags [cohomology-operations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cohomology-operations) and [cohomological-operations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cohomological-operations), with 10 and 20 questions respectively (including 1 with both), different tag excerpts, and a tag wiki for the first one only. I don't know the topic very well, but the excerpts seem to describe essentially the same context. Should these tags be merged?

Answer (score 15):

> **Resolved:** [fixedpoints](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fixedpoints) renamed to [fixed-points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fixed-points).

For consistency with other multiple-word tags. Separating words with hyphens increases readability.

Comment: On the same point, [tag:crossedproducts] should be renamed to [tag:crossed-products]

Answer (score 14):

> **Resolved.** [generalizedeigenvector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generalizedeigenvector) has been renamed [generalized-eigenvector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generalized-eigenvector).

**Proposal: rename "generalizedeigenvector" to "generalized-eigenvector"**

Pledge originally initiated by WillG in [this suggested tag wiki excerpt edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1147115).  I support this proposal since it's a common pratice to separate words with hyphens in tag names in order to increase readability, like [ode](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ode), [real-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-analysis), [generating-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generating-functions), etc.

Answer (score 13):

> **Resolved.** The tags [triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/triangle) and [circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circle) have been renamed [triangles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/triangles) and [circles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circles), respectively.

**Proposal: pluralize [triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/triangle) and [circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circle)**

Putting names of mathematical objects in their plural form is a common practice, e.g. [polygons](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polygons).  We should treat "triangles" and "polygons" equally.

Answer (score 10):

> **Resolved.** [cauchy-riemann-equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cauchy-riemann-equation) is now [cauchy-riemann-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cauchy-riemann-equations).

**Proposal: pluralize [cauchy-riemann-equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cauchy-riemann-equation)**

Because… well, you know: there are two of them.

Answer (score 10):

> **Resolved:** [euler-method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/euler-method) has been merged into [eulers-method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eulers-method), a synonym created, and tag wiki updated.

**Proposal: synonymize [euler-method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/euler-method) with [eulers-method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eulers-method)**

Notice that they are indeed different tags, as the former has user guidance, the latter doesn't. But they are essentially the same thing, i.e. a numerical method to solve first-order first-degree differential equations with a given initial value.

Answer (score 10):

> **Resolved:** The [tag synonym](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/differential-graded-algebras/synonyms) was created.

I suggest a synonym [dg-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dg-algebras) $\to$ [differential-graded-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-graded-algebras).

The tag (dg-algebras) was created in [July 2017](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2017/7/9) (shortly before allowed length of tag names was increased). A short tag-excerpt was also [created at the time](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2351655/revisions). The tag (differential-graded-algebras) was created recently ([July 2019](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2019/7/6)).

It seems clear that both tags are intended for the same meaning. Hence they should be synonymized. (Probably the tag with full name might be more suitable for the master tag - although I'd guess that either way would be acceptable.)

I'll add that synonym between the tags with these names [exists on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/differential-graded-algebras/synonyms).

Since the two tag names are probably due to change in the character limit for tag names, I'll add also a link to the thread about [Expanding abbreviated tag names](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26776).

Comment: Done as proposed.

Answer (score 9):

> **Partially resolved.** [tqft](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tqft) has been synonymized into [topological-quantum-field-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topological-quantum-field-theory). A consensus has not yet been reached on the name change to [topological-quantum-field-theories](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topological-quantum-field-theories).

**Proposal: rename "topological-quantum-field-theory" to "topological-quantum-field-theories" and synonymise it with the tag "tqft"**

An [old question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586296/applications-of-tqfts-beyond-physics) recently had a couple of attempts to change the tags, which were approved (and I agree). In the process, the new tag [topological-quantum-field-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topological-quantum-field-theory) was created, which I agree is better than the previous [tqft](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tqft) tag. However, a topological quantum field theory is a mathematical object like a group or a functor, and so the tag should be pluralised to distinguish it from a subject.

Comment: Wait, *theories*?

Comment: @AsafKaragila A topological quantum field theory is a functor from a cobordism category to a category of vector spaces (with some extra properties). There are many such functors, and so one usually wants to study them as a class of objects.

Comment: There is already a separate post which is related to this: [Some ideas on tags about physical field theory](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29913). I will add that creating a *synonym* between this tag and (tqft) seems like a reasonable idea. (So that both names are left in the system.)

Comment: The first sentence made me cry from the inside, I have to admit. It's always a bit weird when your topic *is* the object. Group theorists don't study "group theories" per se, they study groups. And category theorists don't study "theories of category" per se, they study categories. Sure, you could argue that in fact we study the theories (is this consistent, does this imply that, etc.) but in reality we think about them in semantic terms. So it just surprises me every time when the "theory" part is the object, rather than the syntactic backbone of the object.

Comment: @MartinSleziak thanks I hadn't seen that recent post (which explains why the recent edits were made). I agree that it should be a synonym, so I've edited this post. Asaf, I agree the naming convention is... unfortunate. I think this is a holdover from its history in physics. In fact it's possible that physicists may still study TQFT as a 'subject' rather than as an object. I'm not enough of an expert to comment on that.

Comment: @Andrews I think the usage is different. A TQFT is an 'object' which is studied in mathematics as one member of a class of objects. A particular string theory is a sub-discipline of the subject-area 'string theory' and is not an 'object'.

Comment: Still, "topological quantum field theory" as the subject seems to be widely used. For example, [googling](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=%22topological+quantum+field+theories%22) "topological quantum field theories" returns mostly articles titled "topological quantum field theory", some of which are written by reputable mathematicians (e.g. Aatiyah). Are you suggesting that the subject form is not used among mathematicians working on that subject? (What do they call it then?)

Comment: @AlexanderGruber It's a good question and I don't feel close enough to give an answer. My limited exposure to TQFTs has always been as objects that are studied within category theory/low dimensional topology, but obviously there is a history in mathematical physics to consider. Atiyah's paper is maybe not the best reference point as it was literally the introduction of the definition and things have evolved greatly since then, such as Lurie's classification. Perhaps it's best to check which questions have already been tagged and try to work out which usage seems to be most prevalent.

Comment: If someone with a bit more authority on TQFTs would like to offer their suggestion, that would also be useful. Alternatively, we could make a community wiki post and ask people to vote up/down for their preference.

Answer (score 9):

**Resolved (mostly)** Creation of a tag [gcd-and-lcm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gcd-and-lcm). Merge of the GCD part, not yet merged the LCM part, in case some objection emerges. The tag wiki might need some (more) attention.

---

Proposal: merge [gcd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gcd) and [lcm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lcm)

We tend to combine homologus objects into one tag, like [supremum-and-infimum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supremum-and-infimum), [limsup-and-liminf](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limsup-and-liminf) and [even-and-odd-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/even-and-odd-functions).  It's well known that $ab = \gcd(a,b) \times \mathrm{lcm}(a,b)$, so knowing the [gcd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gcd) implies the same for [lcm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lcm), and *vice versa*.

The [majority](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgcd%5D+AND+%5Blcm%5D) of [lcm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lcm) questions are also tagged with [gcd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gcd).

Comment: A related previous post: [On (gcd) and (greatest-common-divisor) and other similar tags](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20664).

Comment: Maybe to [tag:gcd-and-lcm]?

Comment: @quid I just put a little bit of time into the tag wiki, but I am wondering if, perhaps, the tag info should be completely rewritten?  Right now, it looks like a hodge-podge of facts about the gcd and lcm, without much in the way of guidance about how to use the tag.  I'm not sure what would be better, but perhaps someone more intimate with these topics should have a look?

Answer (score 9):

**Proposal to remove (or even blacklist)** [significance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/significance)

It is a meta tag and it is a bad one. I sincerely ask the creator to stop retagging old questions until we have an actual discussion.

Comment: As of now it has 0 tagged question. Let's hope they will stop now.

Comment: For people who are unaware of the meaning of the phrase "meta tag" I will add a link to the relevant FAQ post: [The “meta-tags”.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2498). I'll also mention this question by the tag-creator: [Relating to create a new tag](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30425).

Answer (score 9):

**Proposal: Add the tag [grad-curl-div](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grad-curl-div); make [gradient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gradient), [curl](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curl) and [divergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divergence) aliases thereof.**

**Edit 2:** I've revised the proposal statement to Alexander Gruber's (in my view superior) suggestion in the comments. Implementing this proposal poses some advantages over the status quo:

- It would (productively) free the > 6k questions about the gradient from the rather broad tag [vector-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vector-analysis).
- It would resolve the weird asymmetry of the tagging situations of the three operators.
- It would reflect the close pedagogical relationship of the three operators, as Alexander pointed out in the comments: In practice many questions about one operators at least implicitly involve one of the others.
- It should in principle resolve the persistent problem of users erroneously using the [divergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divergence) tag for questions about convergence and divergence in the analytic sense.

Proposed tag-excerpt:

> The gradient, curl, and divergence are first-order differential operators that play a fundamental role in vector calculus and its generalizations.

Proposed tag-wiki:

> In vector calculus and in differential geometry, the gradient, curl, and divergence are fundamental first-order differential operators.
>
> - The gradient acts on differentiable (scalar) functions, producing vector fields that encode the direction and magnitude of maximum increase of the function. It can be regarded as a special case of the Jacobian and of the covariant derivative.
> - The curl acts on vector fields and yields vector fields that measure the direction and magnitude of rotation. Unlike the other two operators, the curl is only defined in $3$-dimensions, but it has an analog in $2$ dimensions that is sometimes also called the curl.
> - The divergence acts on vector fields and produces functions that measure the quantity of the fields' source at each point.
>
> These operators have been fruitfully generalized to broader settings. For example, generalizations of the gradient appear in distribution theory and functional analysis, and their applications include the method of gradient ascent (descent) in optimization theory.

---

**Edit** After the discussion in the comments here and in the [Tagging chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/conversation/the-tag-gradient), I went to create this tag, only to find that it was assigned as a synonym for [vector-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vector-analysis) in 2014. That same discussion comprises an argument for de-synonymizing [gradient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gradient), i.e., letting it function as an independent tag. The topic is certainly broad enough: ~6.5k questions mention the gradient; ~4.4k questions tagged with [vector-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vector-analysis). Barring this, it would only be consistent to make [curl](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curl) and [divergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divergence) synonyms of vector-analysis, too.

---

This tag is intended for questions about or involving the gradient operator, which is a major theme in vector calculus and also important differential geometry. Probably most questions using this tag would also be tagged with [vector-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vector-analysis) or [vector-calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vector-calculus), but this operation is particularly important and arises commonly in such questions.

The tag-excerpt would read something like:

> The gradient is a first-order differential operator that measures that rate and direction of fastest increase of a differentiable function.

The tag-wiki would read something like:

> In vector calculus and in differential geometry, the gradient is a differential operator generalizing the derivative that acts on differentiable (scalar) functions, producing vector fields. The gradient of a function at a point is a vector that encodes the direction in which the function increases the most rapidly as well as the rate of increase; as such the gradient of a function is a special case of the Jacobian. The gradient has been fruitfully generalized to distribution theory and functional analysis, and applications include the method of gradient ascent (descent) in optimization theory.

Some model questions for this tag could include:

- [Why is gradient the direction of steepest ascent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223252/why-is-gradient-the-direction-of-steepest-ascent)
- [Difference between gradient and Jacobian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1519367/difference-between-gradient-and-jacobian)
- [Gradient of l2 norm squared](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/883016/gradient-of-l2-norm-squared)
- [What does the symbol nabla indicate?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2710328/what-does-the-symbol-nabla-indicate/)

(At the moment the first of these is tagged with [gradient-flows](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gradient-flows), which is not appropriate, since the question is not asking about the gradient flow o.d.e., and that choice of tag probably reflects the gap that the proposed tag aims to fill.)

The analogous differential operators in ($3$D) vector calculus already have their own tag:

- [curl](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curl) ([$103$ questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curl)), and
- [divergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divergence) ([$687$ questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divergence)),

suggesting that a [gradient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gradient) tag is not too granular. (NB glancing at the search results show that the [divergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divergence) is frequently misapplied, to questions about analytic convergence/divergence. Cf. Arnaud D.'s helpful comment.) Naive searches of questions for the three terms give [$\sim6.5$k results containing $\texttt{gradient}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=gradient+is:q), which suggests wide applicability.

By contrast, question searches find

- [$\sim1.1$k results containing $\texttt{curl}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=curl+is:q), and
- [$\sim4.6$k results for $\texttt{divergence}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=divergence+is:q).

(Again, the latter of these includes many questions about divergence in the analytic sense.) These figures also suggest that if we do not add a [gradient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gradient) tag, then for consistency [curl](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curl) and [divergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divergence) should be removed, thought that change would entail a loss of usability in my view.

When I first raised the proposal in the [Tagging chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/conversation/the-tag-gradient), Martin Sleziak helpfully pointed out that [the tag was previously used in 2013 but then quickly removed in an edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/358250/revisions).

Comment: Note that [tag:divergence] can cause some confusion, so there have been suggestions to [remove it](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29252/misuse-of-tag-divergence-how-to-deal-with-questions-with-the-wrong-tag). But [tag:gradient] seems quite reasonable to me.

Comment: Perhaps divergence could be split into [tag:convergence-and-divergence] for issues related to convergence of sequences/series (so, a synonym of [tag:convergence]) and we could retain [tag:divergence] (per the tag description) or change it to [tag:divergence-operator] for questions about the vector calculus/DG operator?

Comment: In the question linked by Arnaud D., there is a suggestion to rename (convergence) to (convergence-divergence) [in a comment by quid](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29252/misuse-of-tag-divergence-how-to-deal-with-questions-with-the-wrong-tag#comment124216_29252). A the top-voted answer suggests to rename (divergence) to some name which makes clear that it is about vector calculus nad not about series. (Nevertheless, this is only tangential here, but I considered it worth mentioning since the previous comments discuss the (divergence) tag.)

Comment: Right, the suggestion from that answer part of what motivated the suggestion [meta-tag:divergence-operator], which I like better than the suggestions for the tag name given there.

Comment: Well, I did not see that coming LOL.

Comment: You're right that [tag:divergence] and [tag:curl] have no business existing if [tag:gradient] doesn't, but because they are so related pedagogically, my instinct is more to wrap them up into one tag than to emancipate [tag:gradient]. Probably [tag:vector-analysis] is not quite right, but how would y'all feel about something like [tag:div-grad-curl]?

Comment: (Potentially bringing about the best synonym ever: ▽⋅▽▽×.)

Comment: @AlexanderGruber That's a better suggestion than mine, not least because a nontrivial fraction of the questions about these operators at least implicitly involve more than one of them (often via the composition identities $\operatorname{curl} \circ \operatorname{grad} = 0$ and $\operatorname{div} \circ \operatorname{curl} = 0$). But I would strongly recommend listing the operators in the canonical order in the tag name, i.e., [tag:grad-curl-div].

Comment: (Of course, I make no claim that ▽▽×▽⋅ is a more attractive synonym.)

Comment: I've updated the proposal to reflect Alexander's improvements to the suggestion, and I've thrown together a sample tag-excerpt and tag-wiki. I've left the rest of the post the same; some of it is now outdated, but the current intent should be clear from context.

Comment: (Apparently posting in this thread is a good way to earn the Necromancer badge.)

Answer (score 8):

> **Resolved**: [planar-graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planar-graph), [bipartite-graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bipartite-graph), [chordal-graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chordal-graph), and [signed-graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signed-graph) are now [planar-graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planar-graphs), [bipartite-graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bipartite-graphs), [chordal-graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chordal-graphs), and [signed-graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signed-graphs), respectively.

**Proposal: pluralize [planar-graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planar-graph), [bipartite-graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bipartite-graph), [chordal-graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chordal-graph), and [signed-graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signed-graph).**

(To match [random-graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random-graphs), [directed-graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directed-graphs), [cayley-graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cayley-graphs), [infinite-graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinite-graphs), and [hypergraphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hypergraphs), as well as the general philosophy of having things be plural.)

I'm actually not super convinced signed graphs are common enough to deserve their own tag, but if they are to have one it should be consistent with the other tags.

Answer (score 7):

> **Partially Resolved:** [singularvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/singularvalues) is now [singular-values](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/singular-values), but the tag still lacks usage and a wiki.

**Proposal: rename "singularvalues" to "singular-values"**

There's no usage guidance and tag wiki yet.

Answer (score 6):

> **Resolved;** [accessible-categories](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accessible-categories) and [locally-presentable-categories](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/locally-presentable-categories) are created

**Proposal : tag(s) for accessible and locally presentable categories**

A couple months ago someone created (among others) the tags *locally presentable categories* and *accessible categories*, but they were removed. Now this is not really my specialty, but I think these tags could be useful, and in fact I was surprised to learn [from Martin Sleziak](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/conversation/tags-for-accessible-categories-and-locally-presentable-categories) that this was the first time they appeared.

Both topics give some search results on the site, and there seems to be no tag more precise than "category theory" on the questions about them. By the way, the tags exist on MO, and there are also a [book](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Locally+Presentable+and+Accessible+Categories) and a lot of articles on the subject.

Comment: I've created the tag for locally presentable categories; more info [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49649888#49649888)

Comment: And now I've added the tag "accessible categories".

Answer (score 6):

**Proposal: make [smooth-manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smooth-manifolds) a synonym of [manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manifolds).**

In theory, there is a distinction between these tags, with [smooth-manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smooth-manifolds) referring to just differentiable manifolds and [manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manifolds) also including topological manifolds.  In practice, the distinction does not matter for many questions and [manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manifolds) alone is very frequently used for questions that are actually only about smooth manifolds.  For example, looking at the 10 most recent [manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manifolds) questions, 8 of them seem to be primarily or entirely about smooth manifolds but only 3 of them are also tagged [smooth-manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smooth-manifolds).  If you want to use tags to signal that you are interested specifically in smooth manifolds, there are also other ways to do so, for instance using [differential-topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-topology) or [differential-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-geometry).

Comment: If the majority of "manifolds" questions seem to be about "smooth-manifolds", then maybe the synonym should go the other way around, and a separate tag "topological-manifolds" be introduced?

Comment: Willie Wong's suggestion seems sensible to me.

Answer (score 6):

**Proposal:** I suggest to create a synonym between [matrix-groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix-groups) and [linear-groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-groups). (I am not really sure which direction is better.)

The tag [linear-groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-groups) has been on the site for some time, you can see that [the tag-excerpt](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/423730/revisions) and [the tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/423729/revisions) have been created in 2013. The tag [matrix-group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix-group) has been created [recently](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2019/7/7) (July 2019).

As far as I can tell, the two names are often used as synonyms. Even the [tag-excerpt](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/423730/revisions) for (linear-groups) says that: "A linear group or matrix group is a group $G$ whose elements are invertible $n \times n$ matrices over a field $F$."

It's possible that sometimes people make distinction between the two terms. The Wikipedia article [Linear group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_group) says: "In mathematics, a matrix group is a group G consisting of invertible matrices over a specified field K, with the operation of matrix multiplication, and a linear group is an abstract group that is isomorphic to a matrix group over a field K, in other words, admitting a faithful, finite-dimensional representation over K." However, from the tag-info I gather that the intended usage of the tag (linear-groups) was for groups of matrices.

Since both names are used, I suppose that having a synonym might be useful. (A user posting a question will be able to find the tag both if they starts typing "matrix" and if they start typing "linear".)

Comment: I have posted a few additional comments concerning these two tags [in the Tagging chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2019/7/10).

Answer (score 5):

> **Resolved.** [continuoustime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/continuoustime) was removed.

**Proposal: remove "continuoustime" tag**

The tag [continuoustime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/continuoustime) has *zero* questions currently.

Comment: If a tag has no question it dissappears after a day. There is no way for us to remove a tag "more" than having no more questions with it.   (Note that the page would still exist, eg [tag:this-tag-does-not-exist].)

Comment: To add to, here is an older post with a more detailed explanation: [Deleting Tags after being created](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1200).

Answer (score 5):

> **Resolved**: [mirror-symmetry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mirror-symmetry) is now created.

**Proposal: Create "mirror symmetry" tag**

[mirror symmetry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/mirror-symmetry) is already a tag in MO, and there're already several questions about it now in MSE: [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315712/mathematics-and-physics-prerequisites-for-mirror-symmetry), [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773527/construction-of-virtual-class-at-homological-mirror-symmetry), [(3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2149233/mirror-symmetry-of-calabi-yau-surfaces), [(4)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1750814/mirror-symmetry-of-elliptic-curve), [(5)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6484/about-homological-mirror-symmetry).

Here is an [introductory](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~mg475/current.pdf) to mirror symmetry mathematically which says mirror symmetry introduces a correspondence between complex geometry and symplectic geometry, so actually it doesn't require strong physical background in string theory (physically).

---

I've already created [mirror-symmetry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mirror-symmetry) and begin to add this tag to relevant questions gradually, and welcome to improve tag info and usage :)

Comment: I will add a link to a short conversation about this tag in the tagging chatroom: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/conversation/about-mirror-symmetry-tag

Comment: This is probably obvious, but the tag-info should clearly say what the tag is intended for. (Since many users when seeing the tag called mirror-symmetry will use it for problems related to reflections w.r.t. line/plane in geometry and not about the use in string theory, algebraic geometry and related areas.) So maybe it might be useful to suggest what the tag-excerpt and tag-wiki might look like.

Comment: A way which could decrease the likelihood of such misuse of this new tag would be choosing a longer name which makes this distinction clear. (There are already a few such tags, for example, we have ([tag:lattice-orders]) and ([tag:integer-lattices] instead of just (lattices). Or ([tag:magma]) and ([tag:magma-cas]) to distinguish two different meanings of the word magma.) But I have to admit that I don't have a suggestion of a suitable name which would distinguish this tag from symmetry in geometry.

Comment: Can you set up a more descriptive tag info? For example, please list several different aspects of the subject and for each cases, suggests some more suitable tags. (and mirror symmetry is not only about CY, at least they also study the mirror of some fano manifolds)

Comment: @ArcticChar OK. And if you're familiar with mirror symmetry, you can help improve tag info, too.

Answer (score 5):

[Following an earlier discussion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26310/) I approved a synonym [elementary-probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-probability) to [probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability). Likely down the road a merge will happen.

The main reasons are:

- we do not separate tags by level, and in this case there even is [probability-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-theory) that is an "advanced" tag so that further separation seems not useful.
- the community did over the past two years not use that tag much.  In absolute numbers usage is not that bad (about 70), but there are  thousand times as many question in [probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability) overall. Thus, one could say, it is basically just not used at all.

Answer (score 5):

**Proposal : create [grothendieck-group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grothendieck-group) to differentiate from [grothendieck-construction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grothendieck-construction).**

The tag [grothendieck-construction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grothendieck-construction) currently has 18 questions, 12 of which are about the [Grothendieck group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_group) rather than the [Grothendieck construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_construction) (there is no tag-wiki). A search for "Grothendieck construction" (*without* the quotation marks) returns 70 questions, and there seem to be questions about both concepts that do not have the tag.

Since the two concepts are, as far as I know, unrelated, this seems to be a misuse of the tag. I would therefore suggest to create [grothendieck-group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grothendieck-group) (or maybe a less ambiguous name, such as [group-completion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-completion) would be even better) and retag the questions as necessary.

Comment: I upvoted, but I am specifically in favor of creating the tag [tag:group-completion].  Such a tag title seems more descriptive than "Grothendieck group".

Comment: I think there is a dire need for a tag wiki here. I'm somewhat ignorant, but for me *Grothendieck group* only means the group you get from an abelian category by modding out short exact sequences. Similarly, to me the phrase *group completion* would trigger an expectation of seeing questions related to profinite groups and such. In other words, I might unwittingly tag/retag questions here without a tag wiki.

Answer (score 5):

> **Resolved.** [derangements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/derangements) is created.

**Proposal: create "derangements" tag**

I have a sense that the search bar doesn't serve very well for finding combinatorics problems about derangements.  It's especially hard to search for very basic problems involving them, like the hat-check problem.  Another question that seems relatively common is solving and relating the two different canonical recurrence relations for the sequence.

I would contrast this with Catalan numbers, which currently has a tag attached to 297 posts.  Honestly, I don't know if that's a large or a small number in terms of justifying a tag, but I would expect that derangement problems would be roughly as common.

Comment: I used this tag in [my most recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3488665/why-is-n-pmodnk-a-multiple-of-k1-so-often). I also took the time to write the tag excerpt, so if anyone else wants so start using this tag, it's now possible.

Comment: @URL Thanks, I'll get to retagging old questions in my copious spare time!

Answer (score 4):

> **Resolved.** [semisimple-lie-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semisimple-lie-algebras) is created.

**Proposal: Create "semisimple-lie-algebras" tag**

[Semisimple lie algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_Lie_algebra) is an important class of Lie algebras, and we already have tag [semi-simple-rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semi-simple-rings).

Comment: I hope that I have not been presumptious, but there seems to be no objection to this tag, so I went ahead and [created it](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/semisimple-lie-algebra/info)

Answer (score 4):

**Proposal: Create tag "squarefree" and its related tag info**

I was surprised to find that we don't have a "squarefree" tag.  There are about 350 Questions on Math.SE that mention "squarefree" (and about three times that many if all posts are included).  Among other advantages, a tag would provide the wikia summary of basic ideas for this topic in number theory (or perhaps a bit more generally).

I have a dim memory of a discussion of "squarefree" vs. "quadratfrei" as terminology goes, but I can't find it on Meta Math (so maybe it was on a different site or newsgroup altogether).

Comment: It seems that a tag with this name [was created and removed in 2014](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/655358/revisions). This is the only past occurrence of this tag that I found: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49917110#49917110 I did not succeed in finding some past discussions about this on meta, either.

Answer (score 4):

**Proposal: create "linear-fractional-transformation", and synonymize with [lft](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lft) and [mobius-transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobius-transformation).**

They refer to the same thing in most basic cases.

Tag [lft](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lft) is really hard to notice its exsitence, and it only has 16 questions for almost 6 years.

Here's some [discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49991610#49991610) about this.

Comment: Isn't a linear fractional transformation more general?  My understanding is that an LFT may be defined over any field, whereas a Möbius transformation is specifically an LFT over $\mathbb{C}$.  This distinction may not require two distinct tags, but perhaps the tag "linear-fractional-transformation" should be created, with both [tag:lft] and [tag:mobius-transformation] being synonymized with that new tag?

Comment: Problem is I think many people asking about mobius transformations may not know the term linear fractional transformation, so that might be confusing to them.

Comment: I would support renaming [tag:lft] into [tag:linear-fractional-transformation], though

Answer (score 4):

**Proposal: Tag suggestion: [cyclic-symmetric-sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cyclic-symmetric-sums)**

See [Tag suggestion: (cyclic-symmetric-sums)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30228).

Answer (score 4):

> **Resolved**: the tag is [removed](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3283284/2) from that one question.

Please consider removing the tag [4d](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/4d). It is a new tag and has only one question, which is about cube in 4d.

On one hand, it is definitely not necessary to have the tag $nd$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$. More importantly, four dimensional manifold has a special role in differential geometry, so the tag $4d$, if it remains, might eventually contains a mixture of questions in elementary geometry and (very advanced) differential geometry.

I have [tried](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1225392) to remove the tags but some other disagree.

Answer (score 4):

**Proposal:  Remove the tag [infinite-dimensional-space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinite-dimensional-space)**

This tag was created by the question [Are there such things as infinite-dimensional regular polytopes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3452777/are-there-such-things-as-infinite-dimensional-regular-polytopes), which is currently the only question with this tag.  I don't see this tag having much utility.

**Update :** The tag has been removed from the question, and should disappear soon.

Comment: For some reason, I thought that the term "infinite-dimensional space" was just as well established as "$n$-dimensional space". Turns out $\mathbb R^\infty$ is a much more niche topic. Oh well.

Answer (score 3):

> **Partially Resolved:** [stochastic-programming](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stochastic-programming) created. We still need a [tag wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/stochastic-programming/info) and adding the tag to a few [old questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=stochastic%20programming%20is%3aquestion).

**Proposal: create tag "stochastic-programming"**

Reason:

1. It's an area of research.
2. There's over a hundred stochastic programming questions.

Answer (score 2):

**Proposal: pluralise [alternative-proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternative-proof)**.

Reasons:

1. It's a convention to have pluralised tag names if possible.
2. A proposition sometimes has multiple proofs.

Comment: Why downvote for pluralising tags?

Answer (score 2):

> **Proposal: rename the synonym "[`laplaces-equation`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harmonic-functions?tab=Newest)" to "`laplace-equation`" or to ''`laplace's-equation`''.**

`laplaces-equation`is a synonym of [`harmonic-functions`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harmonic-functions?tab=Newest).

I think we should have remove the `s` from `laplaces-equation` or give an **Apostrophe** before `s` (i.e., `'s`) .

There is nothing called `laplaces-equation` rather we can called it `laplace's-equation` or simply "`laplace-equation`".

**Want suitable opinion about my proposal.**

Comment: I think that putting an apostrophe is not possible for technical reasons. Let me try : if we type `[tag:laplace's-equation]` we get as a result [tag:laplace's-equation], but if instead we type `[tag:laplaces-equation]` we get as a result [tag:laplaces-equation].

Comment: I've also tried creating a tag with an apostrophe in the name, and it was treated as two words. So `laplace's-equation` seems impossible to create. Maybe `laplace-equation` would be better, but I'm not sure it's really worth changing a tag that's only a synonym anyway...

Comment: Sorry @Arnaud D. ~~I just proposed to rename the phrase, not to create any tag.

Comment: But the problem is the same : you can't have apostrophes in tag names (as far as I know) so we can't rename the tag with `laplace's-equation`.

Comment: Okay, if so, then we can rename it as `laplace-equation`.  I think it doesn't make sense to have one extra character `s`.

Answer (score 1):

**Proposal: rename [eulerian-path](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eulerian-path) to [euler-trail](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/euler-trail)**

First off, a walk that traverses every edge of a graph is generally not a path but a trail.  Second, when this situation occurs, it is the graph that is described as Eulerian and not the walk (at least IME).

While I'm here, I may as well add that the tag is used to discuss Euler circuits (not to be confused with the again incorrect Euler cycles).  If we were decide to go with [euler-circuit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/euler-circuit) then we may as well also change [hamiltonian-path](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hamiltonian-path) to [hamilton-cycle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hamilton-cycle) for two of the three above reasons.

I just read a wearying [debate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Eulerian_path#'path') on Wikipedia about whether they should rename their page from "Eulerian path".  The opponents claimed that computer scientists misuse mathematical language all the time and "path" beats "trail" in Google Fight.  The proponents' claim that it's wrong did not carry the day.  As a community of mathematicians, I wonder if we might weight the debate differently.

Answer (score 1):

**Proposal: Rename [collatz](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/collatz) to [collatz-conjecture](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/collatz-conjecture).**

Although Lothar Collatz is most known for the $3x+1$ problem (the Collatz Conjecture), I don’t think their names should be used interchangeably. Furthermore, the latter tag has a more informative name.

Comment: The same proposal in the new tag management thread: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31103/tag-management-2020/31112#31112

Comment: As you can see in the corresponding post [in the 2020 thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31103/tag-management-2020/31112#31112), that tag (collatz) was renamed to (collatz-conjecture) by a moderator.

Answer (score 0):

Should we have a [black-scholes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/black-scholes) tag?

We have [quite a few](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Black+Scholes) related questions that are currently spread across different nearby tags (such as [stochastic-calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stochastic-calculus), [pde](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pde), and [finance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance)) but no one tag to unite them.

Comment: Here is [a similar search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Black+Scholes+is%3Aq) restricted to questions, it gives 158 results at the moment. BTW I have asked Michael Greinecker about this tag proposal [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51379257#51379257), so far I got no response.

Answer (score 0):

**Proposal:** I think there is no requirement to place the new tag named [`simplex-method`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simplex-method), which has been created by an user few days ago and already $2$ questions are added here. Since there is already a tag named [`linear-programming`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-programming) and this contains many methods like the [`simplex method`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simplex-method), dual-simplex-method, graphical method etc. etc..

I want a suitable opinion about my proposal.

Thank you.

Comment: I will add that the tag was created a few days ago, on [August 31](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2019/8/31). It seems that some questions about the simplex method are tagged [simplex+linear-programming](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simplex+linear-programming). I will point out that there also is a separate tag ([tag:two-phase-simplex]) for the the two phase simplex method.

Comment: So what you think, is it alright ?

Comment: Actually, I would probably a bit more in favor of the tag. (I have mentioned possibility of creating this tag [in chat quite a long time ago](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35705042#35705042) but I got no response - so it's good that you brought this up on meta, it's more likely that this gets some feedback here.) It would be good to hear from the people who are active in the ([tag:linear-programming]) tag, they are in the best position to judge whether this tag might be useful..

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Let's see what the others say.

Answer (score 0):

**Proposal: rename** `quasiperiodic-functions` **to** `quasiperiodicity`.

**Reason:** posts tagged `quasiperiodic-functions` may also be tagged `quasiperiodicity`, but the reverse is not always true (ie. posts on quasiperiodic tiling or oscillations). Because none of these topics get much attention, there should be one tag to cover all of them.

Comment: Of course, since at the moment there are only [a few questions](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52801163#52801163) in this newly created tag, this could be done manually simply by removing (quasiperdiodic-functions) and adding (quasiperiodicity) to those posts. (In that way you would bump the seven posts which have that tag at the moment - which is not that terrible.)

Comment: BTW in posts on Stack Exchange you can also use the syntax `[tag:tagname]` such as `[tag:quasiperiodic-functions]` or `[tag:quasiperiodicity]`. This will change a bit how the tag looks in the post and also it will be possible to click on it to get the list of questions with that tag.

Answer (score -1):

**Proposal: create "visualisation" for [visualization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visualization)**

The tag synonym instructions suggest the following.

> If you know of common, **alternate spellings** or phrasings for this tag, add them here so we can automatically correct them in the future. For example, suggest “bike” as a synonym for bicycle, or “sock” for socks.

In [mathematical-french](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-french), we use "[visualisation](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=visualisation)" instead of [visualization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visualization).  French regular verbs end more commonly in "-ser" then in "-zer".  [Searching "visualization" on French.SE](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=visualization) gives you *nothing*.  Since French and English develop independently and interdependently, both spellings appear in the Anglo-Saxon world.  Thus, "visualisation" can be qualified as an **alternate spelling** of [visualization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visualization).

Comment: I don't think it's really worth creating French version of every tag... On the other hand, I think this spelling is sometimes used in British English, so it could be useful.

Comment: Once one has types 'visuali' the system will propose the tag. Not needed. Plus, what about opitimiz|sation, and all its variations. Parametriz|sation etc.

Answer (score -1):

**Proposal: rename [teichmueller-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teichmueller-theory) to [teichmuller-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teichmuller-theory) on main site.**

Reasons:

1. I believe it is the correct spelling, barring the ü.

(The only reason I can see why the tag might be spelled as it is is because the ü may change to a ue when it loses the accent, but I do not think this is the case.)

Comment: It is perhaps worth pointing out that at the moment both tags exist, although (teichmuller-theory) was [created only recently](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53005699#53005699). Perhaps creating a tag synonym would be a reasonable solution.

Comment: My understanding is that the procedure for dealing with a German umlaut in a system where umlauts are not possible is to replace the letter with a digraph ending in "e".  Thus ü $\to$ ue.  As such, the tag [tag:teichmueller-theory] is, I think, correct.

Comment: OP's proposal is consistent with https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21349

Answer (score -2):

**Proposal: create "geometry-without-trigonometry" tag**

Similar to the limits-without-lhopital tag, we should have a geometry-without-trigonometry tag. Many times the OP posts a problem hoping to find an "elementary" solution but the answers use trigonometry. The OP may understand trigonometry but wants a pure geometrical solution or he may be in middle school and have no idea what is trigonometry.

The tag geometry-without-trigonometry will hopefully let us avoid such problems just like limits-without-lhopital did.

Comment: Some comments on this can be found under the post: [The geometry-without-trigonometry tag](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30404). (It is now closed - in case the questions gets deleted at some point, the most relevant comment is also saved [in the tagging chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50789104#50789104).)

Comment: @MartinSleziak No one commented on that post except xander.

Answer (score -3):

**Proposal: create tag** "`inverse-fourier`"

I think there should be a tag named `inverse-fourier` which represents mainly the **inverse fourier transform**. I know there is a tag named [fourier-transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fourier-transform) but inverse fourier transform is also an important area of research. It has many application too.

I want a suitable discussion about that. If everything goes alright, then I want to create the tag named `inverse-fourier` . Thank you for your time.

**Note:** There is a tag named [`inverselaplace`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inverselaplace) which deal with questions relating to **inverse Laplace transform**.

Comment: I think that likely something should be done (either follow your proposal or remove inverselaplace). It seems inconsistent to treat Fourier and Laplace differently. (Except if there is an intrinsic reason that escapes me.)

Comment: I strongly agree with you @quid

Answer (score -6):

**Update :** the tag has been merged with [integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integration).

**Proposal:** Keep tag [gradshteyn-ryzhik](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gradshteyn-ryzhik) for questions related to formulas found specifically in the book *Table of Integrals, Series, and Products*.

There are currently about 120 questions about formulas found in the above book, so I have tagged some of these questions with [gradshteyn-ryzhik](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gradshteyn-ryzhik).

Although some people have pointed out that this type of meta-tag is frowned upon, I still believe that it provides added value.

Comment: I'll mention that there were a few discussions on this meta related to a tag tied to one specific book: [Is it OK to create a tag about exercises from one particular book?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29359), [Is the tag \[hoffman-kunze\] necessary?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27658), [Is using subtags to identify book source appropriate for this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13817), [Adding (hartshorne) Tag?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10056). and [Would tags for specific books be appropriate?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28898)

Comment: Given that all previous discussions (linked above) suggest not to have tags for books, can you suggest some arguments in favor of the proposal (besides "I still believe that it provides added value")?

Comment: The idea is that if someone looks for an explanation behind a formula in Gradshteyn&Ryzhik (which does happen quite often), then he can search in this tag to see if his formula has already been explained on this site

Comment: I don't see any reason to keep this tag around.  As Martin Sleziak points out, the community has a history of antipathy towards tags for specific texts.  Moreover, a [quick search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=+Gradshteyn+and+Ryzhik+is%3Aq) does a pretty good job of finding about 120 relevant questions.

Comment: Here is a link to the [conversation in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/conversation/removal-of-gradshteyn-ryzhik) related to removal fo the tag.