# Tag triangle and triangles

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

1. Why do we have tags [triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/triangle) and then again [triangles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/triangles) ?
2. They both seems to have exactly same description. So maybe I am missing something.

Comment: See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29718/tag-management-2019/29871#29871). It is common that old tags will be changed to its plural form (when spotted).

Comment: So it is not really two tags. When you click "triangle", it brings you automatically to the tag "triangles"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Having posted the [linked meta answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29871/290189) in the comments, perhaps I can give an answer.

1. As @ArcticChar has mentioned, it's a convention to pluralize tags if possible, like [cubic-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cubic-equations), [definite-integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definite-integrals), etc.  In such case, the tag name is used to refer to multiple objects of a category, instead of a single one.  For example, [definite-integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definite-integrals) is used for questions involving $\int_0^1 f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$, $\int_a^b g(t) \, \mathrm{d}t$, etc.  The fact that I posted the meta answer addresses the "and then" in the question.
2. They are *tag synonyms*.  A synonymous tag can get remapped to another one.  For instance, [ode](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ode) is redirected to [ordinary-differential-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ordinary-differential-equations) since the former is easier to type.  This feature enhances user experience.  Another interesting example is [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms), which is synonymous to [tag-management](/questions/tagged/tag-management).

Comment: interesting example and meta example are a bit different in my book but I guess you could just redirect them ;)