# Why were all the "triangles" bronze tag badges "Awarded Mar 25 at 4:00"?

Tags: discussion, badges

Sometimes I like to appreciate the smaller things in life.  Like how the [bronze tag badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/798/triangles) for the [triangles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/triangles) tag contains a triangle:

[image]

Nice!

But, what surprised me is that they're all awarded at the same time:

> Awarded Mar 25 at 4:00 to Ross Millikan
>    Awarded Mar 25 at 4:00 to André Nicolas
>    Awarded Mar 25 at 4:00 to Aqua
>    ...

**Question**: Why were all the "triangles" bronze tag badges "Awarded Mar 25 at 4:00"?

---

I might be mistaken, but I don't think anyone has earned a silver [rectangles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rectangles) nor [quadratic-residues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quadratic-residues) tag badge (with a square icon) nor a gold [circles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circles) tag badge (with a circle icon).

Comment: When these sort of things happen, it normally means that there was something wrong with the algorithm and that it got fixed and retroactively corrected. But it's hard to tell.

Comment: I see that the tag "triangles" has a tag-synonym "triangle" so perhaps on that day, the tags were merged.

Comment: Ah, I think you've got it!  The tag synonym is listed as "created" on "Mar 24", although there's also [Tag triangle and triangles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30252/tag-triangle-and-triangles) which is timestamped May.

Comment: Also [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29871/91818) dated March 24 says "triangle" was renamed "triangle".

Comment: @Zacky I guess you could summarize the comments as an answer, your suggestion that it has to do with tag management seems like the most reasonable explanation. You might see similar things with other tags which were renamed. For example, quite recently [the (convergence-divergence) tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/871/convergence-divergence). Or, some time ago, [the (ordinary-differential-equations) tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/784/ordinary-differential-equations).

Comment: @MartinSleziak initially I though that something is off as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms)  it says $60$ (# OF RENAMES) for this tag. I have no idea what that number represents, but it's certainly not the number of posts which were renamed, as there are more than $4000$ posts in "trigangle(s)" tag.

Comment: @Zacky See here for the meaning of that number: [What does “renames” mean in the list of tag synonyms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190477)

Comment: You might appreciate that 325 (as in March 25) is the 25th triangular number.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments on 24 March [triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/triangle) [has been renamed](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29871/515527) as [triangles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/triangles), so all the badges that the users previously had in [triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/triangle) were awarded simultaneously on the next day as [triangles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/triangles) badges.

---

> I might be mistaken, but I don't think anyone has earned a silver rectangles nor quadratic-residues tag badge (with a square icon) nor a gold circles tag badge (with a circle icon).

That's true. One can check it by going to the [top users](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/rectangles/topusers) section of a tag and see that no one within that tag has $\ge 80$ answers and $\ge 400$ reputation earned in that area in order to obtain a silver badge.