# Why is the tag (triangle) listed among the new tags?

Tags: support, bug, tagging

When I look at the [list of the newly created tags](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new) on Mathematics Stack Exchange, the tag [triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/triangle) is listed there.

This seems a bit unusual, because this tag is a [synonym of the tag triangles](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/triangles/synonyms) and the synonym has been created already in March 2019 - both according to [the list of synonyms](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) and [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1178483/data-about-a-tag-synonym?tagname=triangle). There are also some posts here on meta - again from 2019 - which mention this tag synonym: [Why were all the "triangles" bronze tag badges "Awarded Mar 25 at 4:00"?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31079), [Tag triangle and triangles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30252) and the answer related to this tag in [Tag management 2019](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29871).

So how can this be a new tag - when the data about the tag synonym says that this tag existed already in 2019?

---

Here is a screenshot showing how the list of the new tags is shown to me:

[image: screenshot]