# Proposal to delete tag [tag:integer-relation] and [tag:invariant-measure]

Tags: discussion, tagging

[integer-relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer-relation) only has two uses, and neither usage seems to use the tag properly. I suggest we remove this tag (I don't know the protocol for this, please let me know if this is not how one should do this).

Likewise, [invariant-measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/invariant-measure) has one use, and that too is a PSQ.

Comment: well to be fair  neither tag has a tag wiki written up to tell proper usage.

Comment: Since you also asked how the tag removals are usually suggested, I will mention that there also is the [Tag management thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29718). Both options - posting a separate question or posting a new entry in that thread - might be reasonable. (In cases when you'd expect that the discussion is very likely to be longer, a separate question is better.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Ah I didn't even know that existed. Thank you!

Comment: The site has again banned me from asking questions . Last time you said to write an email to a moderator. Please help me whenever you are free . https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31213/595564

Comment: Also I want your help. My this question has received 6 down votes in total and 3 up votes .https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2987286/595564. I want to delete this particular question only but I am not able to delete it. Some users deleted it some days ago. But it had become undeleted again . Please help me to delete this single question

Comment: I wouldn't delete it. Over-deletion is why your account had the issues it did in the first place.

Comment: Also, don't comment on random posts of mine.

Comment: Sorry but please help me for last time . I will not comment again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree that these tags are not needed.

For the former I suggest to retag the two questions (the tag then goes automatically away after a day).

For the latter we might wait for a few days if the question "survives" or not. If the questions should be deleted the tag would be gone too.

For tags that only have a few questions to them, retagging is usually the best way to get rid of the tag. However, except in very clear cases, it makes sense to raise the subject on meta, either via a dedicated thread or in the tag management thread mentioned by Martin. The current version is [Tag management 2019](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29718/tag-management-2019) (usually a new one is posted each year).

I don't think it applies in this case, but if you have a proposal for more general tag that could be used instead then moderator could "merge" the over-specific tag into this more general tag.

By contrast, directly deleting a tag (sometimes playfully called '[burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tags-burnination/info)')  is something that even moderators cannot do, we need SE staff for that. It can be done if it is needed for a large tag, but for non-sizeable tags it is better to deal with it by retags and merges.

Comment: That makes sense, I simply didn't know the protocol. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I also include what Martin said to be more complete.

Comment: Here's another sub-question: what is the policy for new tags that aren't used, and whose usage isn't clear? For example, the newest tag is [tag:acronym], but I can't imagine any good use for this sort of tag (and there are no questions tagged with it)

Comment: As said, tags that are not used at all get deleted. Note that it is not possible to simply create a tag, a tag can only be created by way of being used. Thus what happened is that somebody used/introduced the new tag, and then it got removed from where it was used. The tag itself now will soon go away too.

Comment: @DonThousand I could see a use for that tag if someone is looking for what some mathematical acronym or abbreviation means, but as quid notes, we don't need to worry if that's the case since empty tags go away on their own.