# Why I am not able to ask questions?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, rate-limiting, post-ban

In my profile I have asked 6 questions of which no have down votes. 1 have 0 votes and 4 have 1 up votes and 1 have 2 up votes. I don't have asked poor quality questions (no down votes). It's also written in help center that 2-3 questions cannot affect my position and also I have no downvotes. Can please someone help. With 2 upvotes I am on the positive side and not on negative

Comment: Have you deleted down-voted questions you asked?  Deleted questions, however deleted (whether you deleted your downvoted questions, or others deleted your poor questions you posted), count against one's poor asking record, as well.

Comment: No not in previous 60 days . Might be 1 or max. of 2 very early

Comment: What is the message you get when you try to ask question. Is it this one: "“Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?

Comment: It mainly says questions limit reached in bold. and than yes it's written the same as you say

Comment: When I asked my last question on 1 Feb 2020 . I had not got any warning that time . As I also got a warning on physics stackexchange and on physics stackexchange my performance is very much poorer in asking questions than on math SE . but still I had not got banned . A warning is appearing there still. I think system might have som problem. Since it didn't give a single warning

Comment: I am surprised that you got message about questions limit - since the limit should be [6 questions pre day, 50 questions per month](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4742/should-we-ask-for-question-quotas-like-those-that-have-been-available-for-the-bi/4770#4770). And you're saying that you have no deleted questions recently.

Comment: Flag one of your questions for moderator attention, and leave a message explaining your problem. Or contact the moderators directly. It's only the moderators who can explain your situation to you, and only the moderators who can help you.

Comment: To contact moderators you can go to this room [math mods office](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/math-mods-office) and _ping_  them. Or  you also could request a private chat conversation.

Comment: Why the ban still doesn't lift up . I had received 5 up votes in 2 days . Should I wait for a week or write an e-mail to help center. They had definitely banned me by mistake

Comment: You also have several questions that are closed and deleted and average a score of -2.25, I suspect these influence your current predicament much more heavily than you'd expect.

Comment: Your question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3424457/which-approach-is-correct-and-why-and-why-other-is-wrong has two upvotes **and a downvote**. Your question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2987286/to-prove-pa-cap-overlineb-pa-pa-cap-b also has two upvotes **and a downvote**. So it's not true that your questions have no downvotes, you just haven't worked out how to see the breakdown. (and this doesn't count the deleted questions that I can't see.)

Comment: Thanks to the up voters . The ban is uplifted but warning still appears. Now I will not delete any questions and will try my best to ask good questions. I think that when I was new to this site I might have deleted much questions. May be some months ago

Comment: Warning has also disappeared. Thanks to all those who  had helped me.

Comment: @GerryMyerson "and this doesn't count the deleted questions that I can't see." why you can't see them? You have more than 10k

Comment: @Bella that doesn't give me the privilege of going to another user's page and seeing whether that user has posted any questions that have been deleted. If I have the URL for a deleted question, then I can see the question, but if I don't have any identifying information about the question, I have no way to find it.

Comment: @Gerry just go to your recently deleted page, put their user id number in place of yours, as well as their handle ...

Comment: @Roddy, I tried https://math.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/595564/harsh-jain but all I got was "Page not found".

Comment: They had again banned me. Now what happened

Comment: @Roddy have you actually tried any of the things you write about? All I got was "Note: only content you own is returned when searching for deleted content."

Comment: @Harshjain I don't know what's going on. I would send the mods a detailed email with all of your information, including your suspicions as to why the automated moderation seems to be targeting you.

Comment: @Don Thousand No , now I can ask questions . Now the ban is lifted up and I have also asked a new question. Thanks for offering help. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3540267/595564

Comment: But they didn't warn me before banning

Comment: You may mail for warning if you wish but now I can ask questions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems that you were automatically banned from asking. If you are indeed receiving the message that Martin mentions in the comments, you should read [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/302100) for more information.

Some points worthy of highlighting:

> - Moderators cannot lift the ban.

> "[A]ll questions should be objective, answerable, and on-topic, (...) all answers should be genuine attempts to answer the questions asked, and (...) all posts are expected to have some value for later visitors too. To enforce that, (...) low-quality questions and answers are
>   blocked. This includes posts from:
>
> - users who do not attempt to form coherent sentences
> - users who don't do at least some research themselves before asking their question
> - users who repeatedly post answers that don't attempt to answer the question
> - users who barely even explain what it is they are trying to do

> To avoid bypassing the filter, its internal rules are a secret, but it is partly based on downvotes cast by other members of the communities. If other members of the site consistently give your posts a low ranking, you should try to identify the reason(s) for this.

I'd suggest fixing the formatting, punctuation, grammar etc of your questions as a first attempt to lift the ban.

I'm afraid there is not much that we can do. But...

> If you really, *really* think the ban is an error, then email the team directly using the "contact us" link provided at the bottom of every page. But note that reactivation of banned accounts [is not a high priority](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62373/better-explanation-when-account-is-blocked/62374#62374).

Comment: Can the automatic filters that are blocking some users from asking and answering the questions be removed?